# Display a angular variable in my html page

Tags: angularjs

as the title says I'm trying to display an Angular variable in a html page. I have this function inside the controller I'm using :

```
$http.get('/api/tasks/?format=json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.tasks = data;
        for (var i=0; i < $scope.tasks.results.length; i++)
        {
            if ($scope.tasks.results.status == 0)
            {
                tobedone++;
            }
        }
    });
```

And now I'd like to display `tobedone` inside my html page. I've tried [[tobedone]] (I'm using Django, thus custom providers), but nothing displays. Any help please ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In your template, you have access to all the variables that are members of the current `$scope`. So, `tobedone` should be `$scope.tobedone`, and then you can display it with `{{tobedone}}`, or `[[tobedone]]` in your case.

Comment: Try it and you will see :)

Comment: It is legal Angular expects an expression which can contain literals, operators, and variables.

Example {{ 5 + 5 }} or {{ firstName + " " + lastName }}

@Puce the op knew it works and wanted to know if it is legal or not.